# Trying to assign the value of an SQL Query to a variable SET

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get date in format yyyymm and then use that date in some operation.

```
declare @currdate datetime
set @currdate = (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112))
```

ERROR:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Or if I use below:

```
declare @currdate datetime
set @currdate = SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyyMM')
```

I get same error as above.

So I want if today's date is 17-05-2020, I want 202005 as output and i want to store that output in some variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declare the var as date then

Or you declare a varchar

```
    declare @currdate nvarchar(6)
    set @currdate = (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112))
```

or as clearly precised  by  @MartinSmith

> it is char(6). It is neither variable length nor requires any
>   characters outside of ASCII digits

```
    declare @currdate char(6)
    set @currdate = (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112))
```

or you use  as date

```
declare @currdate datetime
set @currdate GETDATE(),
```

Comment: Please read what i want ...i need 202005 as output for current date if today is 17-05-2020

Comment: then don't declare the var a date but as a nvarchar(6) .  202005 is nvarchar(6) NOT a date

Comment: it is `char(6)`. It is neither variable length nor requires any characters outside of ASCII digits

Comment: @MartinSmith .. correct  ..  answer  updated  with your comment in evidence ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if you want the result as a string or a number.  As a number, it is easy:

```
select year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
```

This is trivially converted to a string:

```
select convert(varchar(6), year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate()))
```

However, your `format()` is just fine.  The issue is the destination type -- it should be a string, not a date.

Comment: I need only to store this yyyymm into some place

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor . . . I don't understand your comment.  Both of these generate a column of the format yyyymm, one as a number and the other as a string.

Comment: generation is fine, it was also about storing in some other variable, but thats been answered. Thank